# Any way to run older versions of OS X on newer Macs?

Tags: macos, virtualization, emulation, powerpc, x86

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Tiger on a Snow Leopard MacBook](https://superuser.com/questions/196524/installing-tiger-on-a-snow-leopard-macbook)

I would like to be able to run OS X 10.3 for the purposes of software testing on a modern (x86) Mac. I'm aware of emulators such as [SheepShaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/) which do this kind of thing for "Classic" Mac OS (up to System 9.0.4), but I can't seem to find anything which would allow me to run a VM for older versions of OS X ?

Comment: Not really a duplicate of the Tiger on MacBook question - this question is about running OS X 10.3 (Panther), which is a PowerPC-only OS, under emulation on a modern OS X x86 system.

Comment: The answer however applies in both cases. The second answer already mentions that the only possible way is using Parallels which only supports Leopard and higher.

Answer (score 0):

There is no PowerPC emulator for Intel architectures. If your target platform is a bit more recent, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/196524/installing-tiger-on-a-snow-leopard-macbook).

Comment: Thanks - although that question is somewhat similar, none of the answers actually provides a solution.

Comment: There is no solution. Old platforms would need to be emulated (which is insanely slow, I tried `PearPC` about 7 years ago), more recent ones, starting with 10.4 Intel, could be virtualized, but neither VMware nor Parallels allow it, since Apple's license doesn't allow it. There was a build for VirtualBox that could do it, but it didn't work on my Macs at all; and I'm not sure if they still do it.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping that there might be a solution which leveraged the Rosetta PowerPC emulation built into Mac OS X for x86 (which is quite fast, incidentally, as you probably know). But evidently not - I guess I'll just have to keep my old G5 Macs running indefinitely.

Comment: @Paul: You use it for software testing, so emulating and tricking are clearly inferior to the real thing. Your users still use 10.3 and earlier? After five years?

Comment: yes, it's for build testing and sometimes for actual testing - we have high reliability legacy systems at customer sites still running 10.3 which can not be upgraded.