# Downgrading Snow Leopard on new mac mini to Tiger

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Tiger on a Snow Leopard MacBook](https://superuser.com/questions/196524/installing-tiger-on-a-snow-leopard-macbook)

Is it possible to downgrade a new mac mini to Tiger in order to run some old software? I don't care how, whether it's dual booting or virtualised or whatever, and I don't nee to keep snow leopard.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/196524/installing-tiger-on-a-snow-leopard-macbook/196559#196559

Comment: There was a build of VirtualBox that could run Mac OS X as a guest system (3.2.0 Beta 1, build 60785, iirc), but it never worked for me, and, as Madison S wrote in the other thread, isn't permitted by the Mac OS X EULA.